# time for my website to get content updated with new content.

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search-console, search-engines, content

It has been 2 months after we launched a website with original content.

During the first month after the launch, we have edited the content so many times and lastly fixed the required content with relevant titles, descriptions and much  more.

And as a result my website was reachable through Google and other search engines and i noticed large number of organic visits.

But when we stopped updating/Editing the content, now i am finding no organic visits and only getting referral and direct visits to my website.

Here, i only want to know when it is good time for my website to get content updated with new content.

And also want to know whether regular content update is good or not..

Comment: I have to add that your site is only 2 months old. You cannot expect anything after just two months. Pay particular attention to how you format your pages/content. Check out this answer for a quick run-down: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/71431/seo-on-single-page-website-and-content-keywords/71433#71433 This is not everything, but the least you will need to do to properly signal what your site is about. Pay particular attention to this. But more than anything, you will just have to wait. It takes at least 6 months to rank for anything especially for a new site. It is not magic.

Answer (score 1):

Regular content updates show search engines that the site is active and since an active site is more likely to be relevant for visitors than an inactive one, the page ranks higher. Regular content updates therefore are great for your site.

The best time to update is whenever there is something to update. Preferably, this would be once or twice a week, but this will have to depend on how much is actually happening to write about. A simple way of doing this is to add a blog or a news feed to your site. That way you have a channel for continuously adding new material to the site. It also has the benefit of showing your customers that things are happening IRL which helps boost credibility.

Answer (score 1):

Basically Not only Google but any search engine love fresh/new content.

Here **Fresh** it does not mean that you update your pages content everyday OR add new pages everyday. But here important thing is your relevant content and popular terms.

Google does something called [Query Deserved Freshness](http://www.nytimes.com/2007/06/03/business/yourmoney/03google.html?_r=1&oref=slogin)

If there’s a search that is suddenly become very popular than its normal activity, Google will apply QDF to that term and look to see if there’s any fresh content on that topic. If there is, that new or fresh content is given a boost in search results.

If you’ve got the right content, on the right topic when QDF hits, you may enjoy being in the top results for days or weeks. Just be aware that after that, your page might be shuffled back in search results. It’s not that you’ve done anything wrong. It’s just that the freshness boost has worn off.

So you can take advantage of this freshness boost by adding relevant content that matches the real-time pulse of their industry.

For ex : it is like "storm". where there is big "storm" at any specific place at that time most people search about that and that becomes popular search. So **news** sites display that news and get more traffic as that is breaking news and popular search in specific time.