# Quick/easy SEO options for a legacy site?

Tags: seo, asp.net

We have a legacy site that offers courses/training. We would like to improve SEO without changing most of the legacy code.

**Based on my research, these are the quick/easy things we can do:**

1. Put the company name at the end of the Page Title
2. Make sure links are keywords instead of "click here"
3. Review content to see if it can focus on search phrases: ("Our technology training"
   instead of "Our Training")
4. Always link to the "domain name" instead of the "default" page (http://microsoft.com instead of
   http://microsoft.com/default.aspx)
5. Create a blog and publish content regularly
6. Use keyword rich captions on images

**Things that are not helpful:**

7. Meta keywords/descriptions
8. Friendly urls

Does anyone have any other quick/easy suggestions we can do to improve SEO?

Comment: Many things on your list will damage existing SEO. Do not use that list please.

Comment: could you let me know how exactly it will be bad for SEO?

Comment: I was about to walk down your list and answer your question before it was marked as duplicate. The list would be too long for comments. But here is some of it. Link to pages not your domain name. Description meta-tag is one of the most important tags there is. URLs should be friendly- easy to remember. Do not over focus on keywords. Make the content speak for itself. Branding the title would be a waste of valuable real-estate without many of the 46 branding signals. I will dig up some links for you and post them in a minute or two.

Comment: Here are some additional links to help get you started: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/71431/seo-on-single-page-website-and-content-keywords/71433#71433 - http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74313/improve-google-ranking-for-general-vs-specific-keywords/74334#74334 - http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74633/well-structured-urls-vs-urls-optimized-for-seo/74639#74639 - http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/69050/my-title-tag-doesnt-appear-to-be-getting-crawled-by-google-properly/69080#69080 Focus on content for humans and not machines. Keep it simple.